# how can i make uneven distribution of lattice without changing the shape of object in the beginning

Tags: modeling, lattice

I want my lattice to the shape as i showed in the beginning. the edge inside lattice is not not evenly distributed, becuz i want my plane to bend along those lines. How can i manipulate the lattice to that shape without changing the shape of my plane immediately?[image]

Comment: I understand if we i use edit mode to lattice it will cause my plane to distort. I am just wondering how can i change the bending position to like this with out deforming my plane in the beginning. plus, i googled but did not find satisfied answers.

Comment: maybe use Mesh Deform modifier or even Surface Deform as your mesh is flat. You'll be able to make the cage mesh exactly fit your object mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you could have something very accurate with a lattice. Maybe you should try shapekeys or, if you have a reason to prefer a modifier, the *Mesh Deform* modifier or even the *Surface Deform*, as your object is a simple plane:

- Create the object A, the one you want to deform.
- Create the object B, a subdivided plane, it's the object that you'll use as the *Surface Deform* target.
- Align its edge loops with the object A vertices.
- Give your object A a *Surface Deform* modifier, choose object B as the target, click on the *Bind* button.
- Select the object B, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape Keys* and create the shapekeys.
- Now your object A will deform rather well.

[image]

Comment: thx for ur answer! I do not have a preference. I just want to bend my surface. I am new to blender and lattice is just the tool i googled and found. So if i just want to bend a surface, which tool will you suggest me to use?

Comment: the simplest one is to create shape keys on your mesh without any modifier, search for a tutorial on youtube: In few words you need to create one basis shapekey which will be the undeformed shape, them create as many shapekeys as you want, one for each deformation you want to create, then play with the vertices in Edit mode, and once back in object mode play with the value...